# Alma Linux 8 cant connect my react app with nodejs server

Tags: reactjs, node.js, linux, apache, deployment

My react app is running on **apache2** and is placed inside **cPanel's directory public_html**. My backend **nodejs server** is also inside the same public_html directory **but its running on linux**, My frontend works fine but its not fetching data from server. I have updated the virtualHost inside this direcotry **"/apache2/conf/httpd.conf"**

```
    <VirtualHost myDomain:8080>
  ServerName myDomain
    ServerAlias myDomian
  DocumentRoot /home/userDirectory/public_html
  ServerAdmin webmaster@myDomain
  UseCanonicalName Off
        # Reverse Proxy settings for Node.js server
ProxyPass /api http://myServer's Address:port
ProxyPassReverse /api http://myServer's Address:port
```

I am running nodejs server through pm2 and its successfully running on 0.0.0.0.port and its responding to the curl command to show all products. but my frontend react app is not listening to it moreover i can type commands like curl on linux and they work fine, but i am unable to access my nodejs server on browser. Please provide any suggestions, thanks for your time.